# Entity Framework migrations remove and update does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Entity Framework migration add works perfectly but the migrations remove and update does not work. What's the problem?

```
dotnet --version
2.1.202
```

Entity Framework Core .NET Command Line Tools 2.0.0-rtm-26452.

Comment: Could you ease provide a bit more context, as to what command you executed and what was the outcome and what the expected outcome you were hoping for.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer below and let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can rollback to any migration by using:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:"MigrationName"
```

For example:

```
Update-Database -configuration YourProject.Migrations.Configuration -Verbose -
TargetMigration:"201903291233013_migration_001"
```

In addition to that you can also delete the migration.cs and its record from MigrationHistory table.